# Missing AdActivity in AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: android, dart, flutter, admob, android-manifest

I am having this error

```
I/Ads     (21352): Starting ad request.
I/Ads     (21352): SDK version: afma-sdk-a-v15090040.14300000.1
I/Ads     (21352): This request is sent from a test device.
W/Ads     (21352): Could not find com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity, please make sure it is declared in AndroidManifest.xml.
W/Ads     (21352): Missing AdActivity with android:configChanges in AndroidManifest.xml. You must have the following declaration within the <application> element: <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />
D/skia    (21352): Program linking failed.
D/skia    (21352): Program linking failed.
```

I tried to resolve the issue as per mentioned in this [missing-adactivity-with-android-configchanges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27438963/missing-adactivity-with-android-configchanges) and [AdView - Missing adActivity with android:configChanges in AndroidManifest.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21973380/adview-missing-adactivity-with-androidconfigchanges-in-androidmanifest-xml) but it having same issue.

in profile/AndroidManifest I have

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="puns.jokes.org.jokespuns">
    <!-- Flutter needs it to communicate with the running application
         to allow setting breakpoints, to provide hot reload, etc.
    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
</manifest>
```

in main/AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="puns.jokes.org.jokespuns">

    <!-- io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication is an android.app.Application that
         calls FlutterMain.startInitialization(this); in its onCreate method.
         In most cases you can leave this as-is, but you if you want to provide
         additional functionality it is fine to subclass or reimplement
         FlutterApplication and put your custom class here. -->
    <application
        android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication"
        android:label="Jokes and Puns"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- This keeps the window background of the activity showing
                 until Flutter renders its first frame. It can be removed if
                 there is no splash screen (such as the default splash screen
                 defined in @style/LaunchTheme). -->
            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
                android:value="ca-app-pub-<app-id>"/>
            <meta-data
                android:name="io.flutter.app.android.SplashScreenUntilFirstFrame"
                android:value="true" />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

What I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I was receiving the same error.

My solution to this problem was to update in the grandle build at the application level.

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.0'
classpath 'com.google.gms: google-services: 4.2.0'
```

My AndroidManifest:

```
 <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
        android:value="ca-app-pub-***********~**********"/>
```

I hope it helps. regards